# Create DataTable child row without showing it?

Tags: datatables

I am using datatable (v1.10.2 with jquery 1.9.2) because I like the out-of-the-box features (searching/sorting etc).  However, now I want the ability to:
1) use animations (sliding) when showing/hiding a row
2) have the hidden row available in the DOM to change (ie, it would exist but have a display:none).

My current code to create the table looks like the following (where formatChild() returns html for a table):

```
 if (row.child.isShown()){
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
 } else {
     row = row.child(formatChild());
     row.show();
     tr.addClass('shown');
 }
```

I am using several services to change data in the child row's table via ajax and want to be able to change that data even when the row is hidden.  I know I can create a map in memory and use the information in the stored map when I show the child row, but to me it is much cleaner to change the hidden row immediately.

I was hoping I could do a row()child(), modify the row, then call row()child().show() but the row isn't created in the DOM after the row.child().

Regarding the animation, I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308566/datatables-jquery-expand-collapse-and-animation) but it involves changing the datatables code :(

I considered just using jquery to add a row to the datatable and hide it, but I couldn't find a good way to "attach" it to the primary row for sorting.

The plan I am currently leaning towards is to add a div to my primary table row that I will show/hide/update rather than using child rows at all.

What is the best practice for managing these hidden areas in a datatable (and showing them with animation)?  ty

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has the same question, I ended up using a DIV in the row rather than using DataTables' child row.  When I add a new row to the datatable, the div is hidden then I hide and show (slideup/slidedown) on a click event.  This gives me the nice animations, keeps the sorting simple, and let's me change information in the hidden row.  Interestingly, the DIV contains a table and the text that is in that table when I create the new row is searchable; however, the text in the table that my ajax call adds/modifies is not searchable.  I'm looking into how I want that to work (and may keep the div out of the search altogether if possible).

Comment: Funny, I had the exact same problem and solved it in the exact same way now, BEFORE reading your post, I just wanted to doublecheck how other people solved it. Seems like programmer's brains work similar.